# How to interpretate zeroinf regression coefficients in R?

Tags: r, regression, poisson, coefficients

I don´t have a good understanding of the zeroinf model, so please I would like you to help me to interpret the coefficients for the next model:

```
Model <- zeroinf(NewClients ~ Discount + Week | Premium , data = DF)

Pearson residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.312103 -0.079842 -0.014251 -0.002827 17.376659 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     2.21423    0.13212  16.759  < 2e-16 ***
Discount        1.45835    0.55525   2.626  0.00863 ** 
Week           -0.26977    0.01363 -19.792  < 2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    2.25130    0.05328  42.253  < 2e-16 ***
Premium        0.44266    0.12861   3.442 0.000578 ***
```

What is the difference with this model and coefficients?

```
Model <- zeroinf(NewClients ~ Discount + Week + Premium , data = DF)

Pearson residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-9.362e-01 -3.346e-03 -8.319e-07 -1.490e-08  1.455e+01 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -5.74330    0.16482 -34.846  < 2e-16 ***
Discount               2.28543    0.57133   4.000 6.33e-05 ***
Week                   0.56836    0.01994  28.508  < 2e-16 ***
Premium               -0.46196    0.13803  -3.347 0.000817 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -11.52169    0.87234 -13.208  < 2e-16 ***
Discount               -7.53305    1.55317  -4.850 1.23e-06 ***
Week                    1.27486    0.08120  15.701  < 2e-16 ***
Premium                -0.04381    0.27801  -0.158    0.875
```

`Discount` is the percentage of discount in a product, `Week` is the week of the year, `Premium` is a binary vector that indicates if the product is considered premium.

Comment: The first model must have been fitted with the `zeroinfl` function, not the `glm` function ...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like you are showing us the right code. Unless I am missing something, this `glm` guessed that you had a poisson distribution and was zero-inflated without you telling it that? You may want to check out this link (and those therein) for help with interpretation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316121/interpret-zero-inflated-negative-binomial-regression